# The Sixth Resident

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

You are in the lobby of an apartment building. You know that six of the units are occupied; however, the directory is in disrepair and only some of the apartment numbers and residents' names are legible:

[image]

---

**What is the surname of the sixth resident, and in which apartment do they live?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the 6th's resident's surname is

> Cohen and that they live in 1D.

After reading Iuri Guilherme's answer, which mentioned that all of the people are in either room A or room D, I thought

> maybe A is for across and D is for down, so I tried to fit the words into a regular crossword puzzle, but with no luck.

In trying many combinations, I found that

> the words fit together, in order, into a cross, like this
>
>  [image]
>
>  The only surname I could find that was 5 letters long and had "OHE" in the middle is Cohen.

Comment: The panel surrounding the elevator buttons gives a hint to the crossword layout (black squares in the corners).

Comment: @fljx Good eye! I didn't even notice that

Comment: You got it! rot13(Gur anzrf ner neenatrq pebffjbeq-fglyr va n tevq funcr gung vf uvagrq ol gur fdhnerf ba gur ryringbe ohggbaf, naq ahzorerq ol gurve ncnegzragf (2Q = 2 qbja, 4N = 4 npebff, rgp.) "Pbura" vf ol sne gur zbfg pbzzba 5-yrggre fheanzr jvgu "bur" va gur zvqqyr, ohg gurer ner n srj bguref fb gur sylre nobhg gur fbpvny rirag jnf vagraqrq nf n xvaq bs pbasvezngvba, vs lbh pna znxr frafr bs vg...)

Comment: @SQLnoob You've solved a few of my puzzles so it's about time for me to get one of yours. rot13(znlor gur yrnqvat yrggref, UAVPF pna or erneenatrq gb VF PUA, be "VF PbUrA"?)

Comment: [One possibility](https://genius.com/Leonard-cohen-the-only-tourist-in-havana-turns-his-thoughts-homeward-annotated) - and [another very different one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_%26_Jerry%27s)!

Comment: @Stiv Nice finds. I found the first one, but only after I solved the puzzle and looked back for the clues I missed. I'm glad I got to this one before you saw it lol

Answer (score 0):

> I made a table with some data regarding the names but I couldn't find any relation. "Ice Cream Social" seems to be a thing of the United States of America, so I figured I'd target the data to that country. "Havana Nights" also seem to be a thing of the USA.

> The numbers come from https://forebears.io/united-states/surnames and represent the rank of the surname - meaning the lower the most common, compared to all others - in the USA and in the World.

> I guessed that the apartment of the sixth person is 1D because everyone seem to live either in the A or D apartment.

> I couldn't find any relationship to the numbers I've put together, so I took a different approach. I decided that the post-it in the board is related to the Dirty Dancing movies. The first one happens in New York while Dirty Dancing 2 - Havana Nights happens in Havana, so I added the ranks for those two cities and Cuba to the table.

> Then I figured that the most common surname both in New York and Havana happens to be Rodriguez. I don't think that is the answer but I added it to the table just for exercise.

> Then I changed the guessed apartment to 1A just because the other boards in which we can see that the B apartment is visible are Spanish surnames and the person lives in the A apartment.

> The resulting table doesn't say anything mathematically speaking (I checked with my regular machine learning algorithms) but it's been some hours of effort trying to figure out and it's the current state of my guessing

| Apartment | Name | New York Rank | Havana Rank | Cuba Rank | USA Rank | World Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | Rodriguez | 3 | 1 | 1 | 14 | 57 |
| 2D | Clark | 646 | 2091 | 1254 | 22 | 545 |
| 3D | Jones | 4 | 1664 | 2224 | 5 | 208 |
| 4A | Colon | 1077 | 1202 | 1146 | 677 | 3339 |
| 5A | Zhang | 759 | 0 | 0 | 514 | 3 |
| 6A | Perez | 12 | 4 | 3 | 40 | 77 |